# How to child a control point of a Bezier curve to an object

Tags: modifiers, parent, bezier-curves

The straight line is a **2D Bezier curve**, with two control points. The bevel function gave it some thickness. The **circle** is a separate 2D object.

Now, when the circle moves, **the idea is that that end of the Bezier curve should move with the circle, staying at the circle's center**. The other end should remain where it is.

So, somehow that end of the Bezier curve should be "attached" to the center of the circle. I thought using the **Hook modifier**. But that requires a vertex group to attach to the object. Bezier curves apparently can't have vertex groups (couldn't find it in the property view), so can't use the modifier. Then I considered using the **parent** function, but apparently a vertex can indeed parent an object, but an object cannot parent a vertex (at least, I couldn't find a way). And anyway, again, Bezier curves don't have vertices. So wouldn't have worked either.

Anyone?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this also?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117061/how-to-draw-distance-lines-to-a-central-object/117236#117236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in a YouTube video:

Suppose you want to make Object A the parent of a control point in a Bezier curve (Object B).

1. select Object A, then shift-select Object B (so both objects are selected)
2. click edit mode. Object B will open edit mode.
3. select the control point you want to "attach" to Object A. click ctrl+H.
4. choose "selected object"

When you now move Object A, the control point will move accordingly, while the other control points of Object B won't, hence deforming the Bezier curve.

PS: you can also use this method when Object B is a simple mesh object (i.e. vertices instead of control points).