# How to simulate a retractable tether for animation?

Tags: animation

I have seen answers and tutorials for how to make animated cables and ropes with physics and the like, but what I need for my project is a little bit different. I'm trying to make a tether for what is essentially a yo-yo that I will need to remain taut when stretched between its two connected objects as well as "retract" as the two objects come closer together, leaving no visible physical slack hanging between them. Is this possible in Blender, or if not what are some shortcuts I could take to create the illusion of such an effect?

Comment: Does the 'retraction' have to be visible in some way, or will it do just to have a line stretched between your objects?

Comment: @RobinBetts Line with some modicum of thickness might do; probably won't need any sort of texture-accurate representation of it reeling back to the source, just need to see a taut line connecting two objects without it clipping into other objects.

Comment: Something akin to this? (rubbery lines) - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117061/how-to-draw-distance-lines-to-a-central-object/117236#117236

Comment: @Edgel3D That did the trick for what I needed, thanks!

Comment: That's good to hear @Cobalt  :)